# Deployment of HTTPBuilder/Rest Plugin in jboss 4.2.2.GA?

Tags: rest, grails, jboss, httpbuilder

I'm not able to use the REST plugin feature of HTTPBuilder to call an http/https link in jboss. As the development was done in grails after creation of war file, it was not able to access the `httpBuilder` classes as required which are already included in the lib folder.

I tried to include the same `http-builder-0.5.3.jar` jar in jboss-classpath, but its still giving the error as `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` while calling the HTTPBuilder method.